# To be the date was August 12. (Is this sentence idiomatic?)

Tags: to-infinitive

> To be the date was August 12.

Is this sentence idiomatic?

What's the difference between 'August 12 was to be the date.' and the example sentence?

Comment: As I told you in answer to your previous question, _August 12 was to be the date_ means that the people planning an event had agreed that that would be the date when it happened. _To be the date was_ makes no sense at all. You could say _The date chosen was August 12_.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that your example sentence is incorrect. We can discuss something arranged, scheduled, decided, or planned using *something* is/was to be *something*.

> August 12 was to be the date.
>
> Paris was to be our destination.
>
> John is to be the leader.

You cannot break the phrase 'was to be' or 'is to be' and move 'to be' somewhere else in the sentence.